# Android Studio- show error on null object reference

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

I'm traing to creat webview app for multiple button bt app make crash
[this is error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CvADm.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Hi, may I know why you used this line "String[] urls = new String[2]"

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post any code and errors as text, not images. See [ask]

Answer (score 0):

can you check is b1(Image button) is exist in activity_main layout file also check web_activity declare in manifest file or not.

Comment: View not found which you have to add click listener, check your id and layout file also in code file yopu have to add findViewById in java files